# Debugging a Macro Merging Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to use the following macro on .csv files with the goal of merging all the data from multiple workbooks in to one sheet in one workbook.

```
Sub cons_data()

Dim Master As Workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceData As Worksheet
Dim CurrentFileName As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'The folder containing the files to be recap'd
myPath = "C:\FakePath"

'Finds the name of the first file of type .csv in the current directory
CurrentFileName = Dir(myPath & "\*.csv*")

'Create a workbook for the recap report
Set Master = ThisWorkbook

For i = 1 To Master.Worksheets.Count
    With Master.Worksheets(i)
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow > 1 Then .Rows("2:" & lRow).ClearContents
    End With
Next i

Do
    Workbooks.Open (myPath & "\" & CurrentFileName)
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks(CurrentFileName)
    For i = 1 To sourceBook.Worksheets.Count
        Set sourceData = sourceBook.Worksheets(i)

        With sourceData
            LastRow = Master.Worksheets(.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Rows("2:" & lRow).Copy Master.Worksheets(.Name).Rows(LastRow + 1)
        End With
    Next i

    sourceBook.Close

'Calling DIR w/o argument finds the next .csv file within the current directory.
CurrentFileName = Dir()
Loop While CurrentFileName <> ""

MsgBox "Done"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

However, I get an error on the following line (and if anyone knows out to add line numbers above that would be much appreciated):

```
 LastRow = Master.Worksheets(.Name).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Namely, I get the error "Run-time Error '9': Subscript out of range".

Normally I would be prompted to open up a folder and be able to select all the desired books, but this is not happening for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the Subscript out of range error because you do not have a sheet in your Master workbook with the same name as the csv file.

Keep in mind that when you open a csv file in Excel it only has one worksheet and the name of that sheet is the name of the csv file (without the file extension).

Comment: I think I see what you mean - is this an issue with .Name then?  Previously when I used this to open .xls files it would use Dir() to allow me to select the desired files.  Would trying to access .csv files change this for any reason?

Comment: @114 Yes, the problem is with `.Name`; there is no worksheet in your Master file with this name.

Comment: Upon further review I do not believe this is the issue.  Name is accessed as a method when grabbing .xls files from a given directory without any issues despite no sheets being named anything other than 'Sheet1'.  The issue only occurs when they are .csv files, and upon copying the data into new files and saving them as .xls files the issue resolved itself.  I have a feeling the issue has to do with how the data is stored in .csv files but I am not certain.

Comment: So you are copying the data to Sheet1 in your Master file. That works when the source file has a sheet named Sheet1. But the csv files will not have a Sheet1 unless the file name is Sheet1.csv. Try stepping through the code to see what I mean.

Comment: Try changing the problem line to this:  `LastRow = Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. And also change this line:  `.Rows("2:" & lRow).Copy Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(LastRow + 1)`.